# How to set max-http-header-size in Spring Boot 2.x application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have Spring boot app running Java 11:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I am getting the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request header is too large`

How to increase `max-http-header-size`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should set on the "application.properties" file:

```
server.max-http-header-size=48000
```

48000 is an example of an excessive header, put whatever you want.

Comment: `48000` is in bytes or kb?

Comment: @Akash bytes. So, in this example, `48000` means 48KB.

Answer (score 21):

From Spring boot 2.1, you will now need to use a `DataSize` parsable value. e.g.

```
server.max-http-header-size=40KB
```

Comment: Great. Worked for me on spring-boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: For additional context, this helped me: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 6):

Please try `server.max-http-header-size`. I have found it here: [Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

The default value for Tomcat and Jetty is 8KB and for Undertow is 1MB.

Answer (score 6):

The `max-http-header-size` property is deprecated since Spring Boot 3.

Now you can use `max-http-request-header-size`:

```yaml
server:
    max-http-request-header-size: 12KB
```

Note: the value must be a `DataSize`, which is very clean. You can use `1KB` instead of `1000`. [DataSize docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/unit/DataSize.html)

Answer (score 2):

In spring boot 1.3.5.RELEASE what worked for me is setting the following entry in application.properties:

```
server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=100000
```

Comment: this tomcat tag is needed